# Get directories from the current to the n-th depth

Tags: python, directory, path

Suppose a directory structure as:

```
├── parent_1
│   ├── child_1
│   │   ├── sub_child_1
│   │   │   └── file_1.py
│   │   └── file_2.py
│   └── file_3.py
├── parent_2
│   └── child_2
│       └── file_4.py
└── file_5.py
```

I want to get two arrays:

```
parents = ["parent_1", "parent_2"]
children = ["child_1", "child_2"]
```

Note that files and `sub_child_1` are not included.

Using suggestions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7159726/947889), I can write:

```py
parents = []
children = []
for root, dir, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    depth = root[len(path) + len(os.path.sep):].count(os.path.sep)
    if depth == 0:
        parents.append(dir)
    elif depth == 1:
        children.append(dir)
```

However, this is a bit wordy and I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this.

### Update 1

I also tried a `listdir`-based approach:

```py
parents = [f for f in listdir(root) if isdir(join(root, f))]
children = []
for p in parents:
    children.append([f for f in listdir(p) if isdir(join(root, p, f))])
```

Comment: Did you also try a `listdir`-based approach, since you have a fixed number of levels you want to look at?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes, I tried that approach, please see the updated question. The second loop was not so exciting to me though.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The problem with `os.listdir` is inefficiency, since for each record it returns you would have to check if it is a directory by making a separate system call of `os.path.isdir`, which is dramatically slow when dealing with large directories. `os.scandir` would be a better choice for this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the directories returned by `os.walk` to prevent it from traversing deeper when it has reached your desired depth:

```
for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    if root == path:
        continue
    parents.append(root)
    children.extend(dirs)
    dirs.clear()
```

Comment: A correction: `children.extend(dirs)` -> `children.extend(dirs.copy())`

Comment: There's no need to make a copy of `dirs` because the `list.extend` method would copy the  values of `dirs` into `children` already.

Comment: I was using `append` and was losing info after `.clear()`. Thanks for the clarification.